# Label not visible above ToolStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, z-order

At runtime I add (and remove) several controls, as needed, to a main window which in Designer contains only a ToolStrip with some function buttons. In some cases I want to add an info label next to the toolStrip, but I cannot make it visible, ie. it is hidden below. The code for the label is straightforward

```cs
infoLabel = new Label();
infoLabel.AutoSize = true;
infoLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 10);
infoLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
infoLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
infoLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 13);
infoLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
infoLabel.TabIndex = 1;
infoLabel.Text = "this is info";
infoLabel.BringToFront();
this.Controls.Add(infoLabel);
```

`TabIndex` and `BringToFront` I added as an act of desperation, it does not help. BTW the ToolStrip's `TabIndex` is 2, and its `BackColor` I changed to transparent.

However, when I placed a label over the ToolStrip in the Designer, it is visible (ie. on top). I analysed the code then but did not see anything different from what I am writing. What am I missing here?

Comment: `infoLabel.BringToFront();` *after* `this.Controls.Add(infoLabel);`? We first add `infoLabel` onto `this` and then make `infoLabel` be the *topmost*

Comment: Yup, BringToFront() cannot do anything when the control was not yet added to its parent.  Nothing it can be in front of yet.  An exception would have been useful.

Comment: yes, it works! many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest calling `infoLabel.BringToFront();` at the very end, at least *after* `this.Controls.Add(infoLabel)`; you current code amended:

```
infoLabel = new Label();
...
infoLabel.Text = "this is info";

// First Add to this
this.Controls.Add(infoLabel);

// Only then we can make infoLabel be the topmost 
// among all existing controls which are on this
infoLabel.BringToFront();
```

We create `infoLabel`, add it to `this` and finally make it *topmost* on `this`. To make code more *readable* I suggest something like this:

```
// Create a label on this
infoLabel = new Label() {
  AutoSize  = true,
  Location  = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 10),
  Size      = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13),
  BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control,
  Font      = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 13),
  ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black,
  TabIndex  = 1,
  Text      = "this is info",
  Parent    = this // <- instead of this.Controls.Add(infoLabel);
};

// make infoLabel topmost among all controls on this
infoLabel.BringToFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms controls do not have a property which you can use to set z-index of controls like one can do in CSS.

You'll need to call `Parent.SetChildIndex(control, 0);`. The control at the front of `Controls` collection is the topmost in z-order for a container control.